# Akka: Serializable Props

Tags: java, scala, serialization, akka, akka-cluster

Base on [Akka documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/serialization.html#verification):

> If you want to verify that your Props are serializable you can enable
>   the following config option:

```
akka {
  actor {
    serialize-creators = on
  }
}
```

My question is Should `Props` be serializable? Why?

Is it because of accessing `ShardRegion`?

```
ClusterSharding.get(actorSystem)
    .start("Devices", Device.props(x, y) , settings, new DeviceMessageExtractor(t));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Props object should be serializable if you want to create actor remotely. This object will be sent to remote system than remote system will create actor.

Please look at "Creating Actors Remotely" section of https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/remoting.html .

Comment: I don't use `akka-remote `directly, so i don't create actors remotely. I'm using `akka-cluster`. So in which cases, akka-cluster decides create actors remotely? in creating shard-actors by `ShardRegion` (my example)?

Comment: You will have several nodes in the cluster, so each node will have several shards and you do not know where your actors are deployed. As an example, you start one node and create your actors, then you add the second node, you actors will be rebalanced and redeployed from the first node to second(example for sharding stratagy).